# Mongodb C++ driver install on Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, boost, scons

I have installed this driver for long time, but failed. There is the same mistake as following:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt... (cached) no
Checking for C++ library boost_thread... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ library boost_filesystem-mt... (cached) no
Checking for C++ library boost_filesystem... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ library boost_system-mt... (cached) no
Checking for C++ library boost_system... (cached) yes
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/mongo/client/dbclient_rs.o -c -O3 -pthread -D_SCONS -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -Ibuild -Isrc -Ibuild/mongo -Isrc/mongo src/mongo/client/dbclient_rs.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:24,
                 from src/mongo/util/paths.h:26,
                 from src/mongo/db/client.h:38,
                 from src/mongo/db/curop.h:23,
                 from src/mongo/db/curop-inl.h:1,
                 from src/mongo/db/instance.h:23,
                 from src/mongo/db/dbmessage.h:25,
                 from src/mongo/client/dbclient_rs.cpp:27:
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/config.hpp:16:5: error: #error Compiling Filesystem version 3 file with BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION defined != 3
scons: *** [build/mongo/client/dbclient_rs.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of erro`enter code here`rs.`enter code here`
```

before install, I have installed the boost 1.5， pcre8.3, and I want install mongodb driver 2.2 
Any ideas ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem with you. 
In mongodb C++ driver source `src/mongo/pch.h`

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2
```

but in `/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/config.hpp`:

```
# if defined(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION) && BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION != 3
#   error Compiling Filesystem version 3 file with BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION defined != 3
# endif
```

this is the problem. 
And I change `src/mongo/pch.h` to

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3
```

then scons again, the compiles correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Some solution from Internet :

> RESOLVED: I have v2 of the 1.44 boost libraries, but had "#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3" in my header (a co-worker using another version had added it). If I comment this directive, my code compiles correctly. Looks like we need to synchronize our libraries.

Comment: just conmment this diretive, every thing is OK?